# SonarQube method usage report

Tags: java, junit, sonarqube

Is there a way to tell SonarQube to report methods, whose only calls are JUnit tests?

We do have SonarQube in use and I found one case like mentioned above - now I'm wondering how much of these false negatives we have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume what you meant to say is "whose only calls are FROM JUnit tests"?

I doubt there is anything like that.

The problem you're seeing is the difference between public interfaces and private interfaces.  You should ensure that those are clearly delineated, and your tests should only use the public interfaces.  If you end up finding code that you're unable to get to from tests, that's the situation you're looking for.  It's easier to find the code that it's impossible to get to, as opposed to finding methods that are only called from tests.